# Round function in SQL remove .00

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to round any float value with 2 decimal places while after decimal has values and if after decimal has no values like (.00) at that time will not be shown .00

Please refer this code

```
  Declare @num float
  Set @num = 123.23252
  --1. Result 123.23
  select CAST(ROUND(@num,2) as numeric(18,2))
  Set @num = 253.000012
  --2. Result 253.00
  select CAST(ROUND(@num,2) as numeric(18,2))
```

I need 1st result is ok but in 2nd result i want only 253 (not included .00). These both functionality i want to be same function or method because we don't know exactly when @num has 123.23 or 253.000012.

Please let me know the simple and optimized solution.

Comment: well in the world of Mathematics `253 = 253.00` , your issue is the return data type, `253` is an integer value, `253.00` is a decimal value with precision of two decimal places, having one function return two different data types `NOT A GOOD IDEA` .

Comment: May be presentation layer should do this

Comment: As M.Ali and Fireblad alread told you: this is nothing to do in a DBMS! "mixed types" for one column/expression is not practicable. The formatting can be done later. Use your database for what it's ment for...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Declare @num float
  Set @num = 123.23252
  --1. Result 123.23
  select CAST(ROUND(@num,2) as numeric(18,2))
  Set @num = 253.000012
  --2. Result 253.00
```

Use case when like this:

```
    select 
    CASE 
        WHEN RIGHT(CAST(ROUND(@num,2) as numeric(18,2)),2)='00' THEN ROUND(@num,2) 
        ELSE CAST(ROUND(@num,2) as numeric(18,2)) 
    END
```

Or use IFF for SQL Server 2012:

```
 select IFF(RIGHT(CAST(ROUND(@num,2) as numeric(18,2)),2)='00'
      , ROUND(@num,2), CAST(ROUND(@num,2) as numeric(18,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Format to do this(SQL SERVER 2012+)

```
    Set @num = 253.000012
  select FORMAT(CAST(ROUND(@num,2) as numeric(18,2)) , 'g15')
    --3. Result 253.00

        Set @num = 253.3000012
  select FORMAT(CAST(ROUND(@num,2) as numeric(18,2)) , 'g15')
    --4. Result 253.3
```

Answer (score 0):

The presentation of data should be done by the client, not by the database, but if you insist, just round the float and keep it as float:

```
declare @num1 float = 123.23252;
declare @num2 float = 253.000012;

select ROUND(@num1,2), ROUND(@num2,2)
```

**result**

```
123.23  253
```